# Linux software to handle external Self-Encrypted Drives

Tags: linux, encryption, hard-disk

I have an external HDD supporting [hardware encryption](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/commonly_asked_questions_and_answers_on_selfencrypting_drives) which I can access by issuing `hdparm --security-unlock PWD /dev/sdx` before mounting. Besides usability issues (automount cannot be used because the password must be entered first), entering password on the command line is a big security issue with HDD password being spread across the file system.

I'm looking for a more secure and user-friendly solution:

1. The drive automount process should be interrupted to allow the user to enter HDD password, and resume once the password was entered.
2. User should be prompted for password in a secure way, so that the password doesn't end up stored in cleartext in `/home/user/.history` and `/proc/pid/cmdline`
3. A nice feature would be to use a password from a [keyring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring), so that the user just connects the drive and it gets automounted without any prompt for password.